# What is the difference between ID-1 sim & Plug-in Sim cards?

Tags: sim

Firstly, please forgive me if this is not the right place to this question. I was confused and couldn't understand where to ask this question.

I want to know in simple terms, what are difference between `ID-1 sim cards` and `Plug in` sim cards.

I found the `gsm standard documentation` from [**here**](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/100900_100999/100977/08.14.00_60/ts_100977v081400p.pdf). Please tell me the difference between ID-1 sim & Plugin sims

Answer (score 1):

ID-1 has the size of a credit card. "Plug in" is the same as the Mini-SIM card, roughly 25 mm × 15 mm in size.

You'll find the definition in Annex A of the PDF you've linked btw.